# How to display 30 row in listview with different view i need to display

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

How to display 30 row in listview with different view I need to display 1 4 7 10 13 .......textview 2 5 8 11 14 .......edittext view 3 6 9 12 15 .........image view

here the code getting some error

```
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(position==0){
        v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.secondactvity, null);
        TextView t1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t1.setText(names[position]);
        Log.d("View Number", position+"");
    }
    else if(position==1){
        v=Inflater.
        Log.d("View Number", position+"");
        EditText e1=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }
    else if(position==2){
        v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.thirdactivty, null);
        ImageView im1=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        im1.setImageResource(img[position]);
        Log.d("View Number", position+"");
    }
```

Comment: create item file with textview,edittext and imageview now handle this with dynamically on particular position hide gone hide gone,

Comment: @Jignesh Jain i m already created  in xml file

Comment: @Jignesh Jain i m getting proper values in log cat but in emulate showing in properate values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions to successfully display different row.

The first one is, like suggest @Jignesh Jain, to have one layout with all type of view and use `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the view you do not want for each row.

The second one (and better i think) is to use different view type by implementing `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int position)`. With this to method the convertView in `getView` will always be of the good type (if not null) and can be reuse as usual.

Comment: @Jignesh Jain  here i m giving string values 
 String [] names={"name1","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6","name7","name8","name9","name10",
   
   };

Comment: @Jignesh Jain   it displays only name 1 but not increment for next values